# No result produce with a well-designed bisection search

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote such a bisection search,

The steps illustrates:
1.  check if empty
2. select mid index as entry test
3. recursively search
4. base case is find == nums[mid]

```
In [14]: %paste                                                                                       
from typing import List

def bi_search(nums: List[int], find: int) -> int:
    """
    mid value is the key here.
    """
    if len(nums) == 0:
        return -1
    else:
        mid = len(nums) // 2  #testEntry
        if find == nums[mid]:
            return mid 
        if find < nums[mid]:
            sub_nums = nums[:mid]
            bi_search(sub_nums, find)
        if find > nums[mid]:
            sub_nums = nums[mid:]
            bi_search(sub_nums, find)

## -- End pasted text --
```

Run it

```
In [15]: nums = list(range(1000))                                                                     
In [16]: find = 456                                                                                   
In [17]: result = bi_search(nums, find)                                                               
In [18]: result                                                                                       
In [19]:
```

I double-checked my procedures but find no errors.

What's the problem with my bisection search?

Comment: You're missing a couple of `return` statements in front of the recursive calls.

Comment: sorry, I do not get your point,  return mid as the base case @Kevin

Comment: **`return`** `bi_search(sub_nums, find)`

Comment: @Alice: The base case is not a "recursive call."

Comment: thank you all. I assume I have a feeling of algorithms now, the key is testing(hypothesis) and updating.